# node.js ws: How to identify which websocket sent a message?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am wondering if the server implementation in the ws library allows to find out, which connected client triggered a message event. I am hoping I can avoid to dive into the code to find out...

Thanks!

P.S.: I am aware of the [FAQ: How to get the IP address of the client?](https://github.com/websockets/ws#how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-client), but that refers to the situation of a new connection. I am interested in the event of an incoming message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait, never mind - I figured it out. It is actually pretty obvious.

When you define the closure that deals with a message for a websocket `ws`, you have to be in a context where ws is defined - i.e., the closure of the websocket server `wss`'s `on`-function for the 'connection' event. And there you also have access to the request object `req` that gives you the remote address:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
  console.log('connected: '+req.connection.remoteAddress);
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received from %s: %s', req.connection.remoteAddress, message);
    // do stuff with the message
  });
});
```